# Representing Calculation Schemes as Hierarchy in SSAS (maybe Replacing dimension members)

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I am looking for a best practice and a solution in general to represent reporting hierarchies in an SSAS dimension. This is needed so business user can easily interact with the calculation scheme from Excel.

Have a look at the following hierarchy:

[image: real hierarchy]

However I want it to be represented as shown in the following screenshot:
[image: wanted]

That screenshot has a value for `DB1` (the sum of `TURNOVER` and the real `DB1`).

As an idea I added the following code to the Cube:

```
Scope([DIM Contribution Margin].[Hierarchy].[CM1 KEY].&[DB1]);
  This =  [DIM Contribution Margin].[Hierarchy].[CM1 KEY].&[DB1]
        + [DIM Contribution Margin].[Hierarchy].[CM1 KEY].&[TURNOVER];
End Scope;

Scope([DIM Contribution Margin].[Hierarchy].[CM1 KEY].&[DB2]);
  This =  [DIM Contribution Margin].[Hierarchy].[CM1 KEY].&[DB2]
        + [DIM Contribution Margin].[Hierarchy].[CM1 KEY].&[DB1];
End Scope;
```

However this affects the All Member of the Dimension which propagates to all other dimensions. Thus I figured I should not increate the regular aggregate value of the dimension and added:

```
Scope([DIM Contribution Margin].[Hierarchy].[CM1 KEY].&[-1]);
  This =  [DIM Contribution Margin].[Hierarchy].[CM1 KEY].&[-1]
        - [DIM Contribution Margin].[Hierarchy].[CM1 KEY].&[DB2]
        - [DIM Contribution Margin].[Hierarchy].[CM1 KEY].&[DB1];
End Scope;
```

However this somehow still influences the other dimensions.
I am thankfull for every idea how to solve this in an SSAS dimension.

I have the following ideas:

- The dimension representing the calculation schema, does not have to aggregate. But isAggregate = false is not a solution as I would have to select a default member...
- I tried using calculated dimension members, however they can just be leaves and no nodes, so it will not work.
- Calculated dimension members are impossible to place at an exact position to my knowledge, the allways appear at the end, thus no chance for a workarround there.

Answer (score 0):

I would add one or more levels at the top of the hierarchy to manage your DB1 and DB2 totals, using automatic aggregation.  I would populate the source columns to group the data e.g. your current TURNOVER and DB1 members would sum to a DB1 member at a higher level.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. This was my initial thought as well. However, while the hierarchy sums up beautifully in this case. It has a structure which is not the reporting struture. I would have DB2 as root node cotaining INDIRECTCOST und DB1 an so forth. Thus the turnover is on the third level. I would like to be able to drag and drop the wanted reporting structure in Excel.